# How do I stop explorer.exe from crashing with Data Execution Prevention (windows XP)

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer, dep

At least once a day or more my explorer.exe crashes with the error "Data Execution Prevention - To help protect your computer, Windows has closed this program.  Windows Explorer  [Close Message]"

explorer appears to continue running until you press the close message button, at which time explorer stops running (you can see the taskbar and desktop disappear) and then it automatically restarts itself (explorer.exe I mean, not the whole PC) and the taskbar and desktop come back.

Event Viewer says: "Faulting application explorer.exe, version 6.0.2900.5512, faulting module unknown, version 0.0.0.0, fault address 0x038e33ec."

Comment: use this tool to disable 3rd party addons until you find the addon which crashes the explorer: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I had already done that for a few items but it didn't solve it (was hoping for some other kind of solution) However, I went back in and disabled a couple more and it still crashed. So I went back in and disabled another couple more and now it seems to no longer crash (but only time will tell)